# Merging cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub colorcells()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("Range1")
        If InStr(cell.Value, "Person1") > 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbSienna
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Value, "") > 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGrey
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Value, "") = 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Hello,
The last function in the code cleans my cells if there are no colours. I would like to add merge cells (because I use multiple coloured cells) and apply all borders to the cell.
I tried some but it didn't work it is probably because I can't use `Dim cell As Range` for merging them.
Thank you for your help.

---

Thanks for the answers. I couldn't explain well. I wish to merge the cells after this

```
ElseIf InStr(cell.Value, "") = 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite
```

What i want to do is a cleaning. If there are no strings, my code makes that cells white. Then i need it also merges the cells which does not have a string value.

Comment: Merged cells are BAD, BAD, BAD and should be avoided. Just create a border around several cells. If you want to center the text, use `.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection`

Comment: Although @teylyn's comment has been upvoted, I cannot agree. Merged cells should be used with caution but they provide functionality that is not available any other way. You can ask if a cell is part of a merged area and what that merged area is so they can be maintained and managed. If you use `xlCenterAcrossSelection` to centre across A:C and separately across D:F, you cannot later detect which cells are part of which group. If there is useful functionality associated with `xlCenterAcrossSelection`, I would like to know about it.

Comment: You say you want to add merged cells to your sub routine but you do not say why you cannot. Please describe your problem.

Comment: Merging all empty cells seems a strange requirement.  You can only merge a rectangle.  If, for example, you merge G18:G19 then merge G18:H18 then you merge G18:H19.  Have you looked at how Ralph determines if (1) a cell is merged and (2) if it the top left cell of the merged area?

Comment: Just noticed `InStr(cell.Value, "")`. This will always return 1. `Do you mean cell.Value <> ""`?

Answer (score 0):

I am also a bit hazy as to what you might want to achieve. The code you provided seems to work rather fine to me. Yet, if you want to treat merged cells somewhat differently then the following code adaptation might be of help:

```
Sub colorcells()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("Range1")
    If cell.Address = cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Address And cell.MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Debug.Print "Here is a merged cell range starting (top left corner): " & cell.Address
        cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
    Else
        If InStr(cell.Value, "Person1") > 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbSienna
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Value, "") > 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGrey
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Value, "") = 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite
        End If
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```